# Spring-boot with MySQL - RESTful API web-service: SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22, Unknown column in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm making a RESTful API web service with Spring Boot and MySQL. At the top level, I have an entity `sites`. On a second level an entity `floors`. Each `site` may have several `floors`.
Here is class `Floors`:

```
@Entity
public class Floors {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String floor;

    @ManyToOne
    private Sites site;

    public Sites getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(Sites site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    public Floors(){}

    public Floors(String id, String floor, String siteId) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.floor = floor;
        this.site = new Sites(siteId, "", "");
    }

//getters and setters
```

Here is `FloorsController`:

```
@RestController
public class FloorsController {

    @Autowired
    private FloorsService floorsService;

    @RequestMapping("/api/sites/{id}/floors")
    public List<Floors> getAllFloors(@PathVariable String id){
        return floorsService.getAllFloors(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/api/sites/{siteId}/floors")
    public void addFloor(@RequestBody Floors floor, @PathVariable String siteId){
        floor.setSite(new Sites(siteId, "",""));
        floorsService.addFloor(floor);
    }

}
```

Here is `SitesService`:

```
@Service
public class SitesService {

    @Autowired
    private SitesRepository sitesRepository;

    public List<Sites> getAllSites(){
        List<Sites> sites = new ArrayList<>();
        sitesRepository.findAll()
                .forEach(sites::add);
        return sites;
    }

    public void addSite(Sites site){
        sitesRepository.save(site);
    }
}
```

And here is my `FloorsRepository`:

```
public interface FloorsRepository extends CrudRepository<Floors, Integer> {

    public List<Floors> getFloorsBySiteId(String siteId);
}
```

Then in MySQL Workbench, I created two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `employeelocator1`.`sites` (
  `id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `site` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `employeelocator1`.`floors` (
  `id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `floor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `siteId` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_siteId_idx` (`siteId` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_siteId`
    FOREIGN KEY (`siteId`)
    REFERENCES `employeelocator1`.`sites` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

When I use `/api/sites` to get the list of all sites it works well. But when I try to get the list of all floors in site #1 using `/api/sites/1/floors`, I get an error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'floors0_.site_id' in 'field list'
```

Is it due to something wrong with my database and tables? Or something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my question. FK in `floors` table should have been named `site_id` and not `siteId`

Answer (score 0):

In the `Sites Entity`, you also can define like this to solve your problem:

```
@Id 
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private String site_id;
```